# jQuery - In Page Popup with faded background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm pretty new to jQuery and honestly haven't got a clue where to begin.

**What I want** - A 5 second timer on page load that triggers a popup inside the page.  I'd like it to popup in the center of the screen and be to add content/style it however I'd like, ideally with my own dimensions.  A faded background would be great too!  But I can live without if I'm asking too much.

I can do the timer, but only really know how to add an alert inside... Which isn't quite the desired outcome.

**What I can do**

```
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert ('Hello');
    }, 5000);
```

Any help or guidance would be great!

Thanks :)

Comment: This question has a few good examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758733/jquery-modal-window-example

Comment: Thanks for that!  I wasn't aware of what I needed to search!  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever heard about **jQuery UI**?

jQuery UI is a extension to jQuery and allows you to add things like dialog windows, modal messages, accordeons, custom buttons, datepickers and much, much more.

https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message
*This would maybe interesting for you, because of the dialog/popup thing...*

I hope I could help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use Twitter Bootstrap and it's build it modal function. Once it's modal pops up, the background will also fade. Here is some code:

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">...</div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}, 5000);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Starfire1337/9aJYW/

Comment: That looks quite similar to what I'm after - Where is the style being pulled from on this?  Thanks

Comment: Twitter Bootstrap CSS provides the style, as in the beginning I have included the CSS for bootstrap. If you don't want all of twitter's CSS, I believe that you could create a "custom" version of it and download it here: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/. Make sure you select all the options regarding to modals. If you were to edit the CSS, you could also customize the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very crude example with little styling:

css:

```
 #target {
    display:none;
 }
```

js:

```
 setTimeout(function() {
     $('#target').show();
 }, 5000);
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/9GMZ7/

Answer (score 0):

0 I like to have a hidden class

```
 .hidden { display : none }
```

1 Create the background overlay

```
.overlay{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    z-index : 50; //keep above all other things on page so no clicky

}
```

2 Create the container for your popup

```
.popoup{
    position : fixed;
    margin-left : auto;
    margin-right : auto;
    border : solid thin #000;
    width : 500px;
    height : 500px;
    z-index : 100;
}
```

(css may need some work but you get the idea, background transparent full div, centered higher z-indexed content)

3 create the html

```
 <body>
 <a class="show">Show Popup</a>
 <div class="overlay hidden"></div>
 <div class="popup hidden"><h1>Popup content</h1></div>
 </body>
```

4 add jquery

```
 $(".show").click(function(){
    $(".overlay").removeClass('hidden');
    $(".popup").removeClass('hidden');
}
//Close when click on overlay
$(".overlay").click(function(){
    $(".overlay").addClass('hidden');
    $(".popup").addClass('hidden');
}
```

5 Customize with animations and more fun stuffs. Maybe make a jQuery plugin? Explore!

6 Profite

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'm struggling to get this to work in JSFiddle.  Any ideas why?  http://jsfiddle.net/8X7a2/

Comment: It's not really ready for production off the bat, just kind of an idea of one way to do it. I made it work here http://jsfiddle.net/8X7a2/15/ but you'll need to do some css research on your own to get it to float properly and get the overlay fully behind it. If you don't figure it out I'll see what I can do.
I'm sure if you research it a bit you can get it in no time

Comment: Also, if your working with javascript you need to know how to use the console to see when errors occur ( which was the problem in your js fiddle)